# Rename specific files

Tags: regular-expression, rename

I am in need to rename files in a directory, for example from

```
11-Vnnn_S2_L001_aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd.ext
```

to

```
Vnnn.ext
```

Is there a way to do that with `basename` command in Linux?

I am very new to coding, so I will be happy for some explanation.

Comment: Give least 3 existing and desired file name example

Comment: Welcome to the site. The requirements of your question are not quite clear. Are all filenames named according to the above pattern, i.e. with `-` and `_`-separated components? Can a `-` or `_` occur _inside_ the part you want to keep? Is the part you want to keep always `V` + 3 digits (otherwise, what does `n` stand for)?. Do you plan to do this in a shell script? Which shell are you using? Please edit your question to include that information (and possible more examples), so that contributors have all information at a glance.

Comment: Try to use sed/cut to get the desired result. How to do that is your task...

Comment: All filenames are named like that - first "-" and remained "_" as delimiters
The part I want to keep is like VSnnn - with five symbols

Comment: @SHW this is not a task for `sed` or `cut`, as we're changing filenames, not textfiles. It's a task for `rename`.

Comment: @SHW You can't/shouldn't use line-oriented text editing tools to modify filenames as filenames may contain newlines (even though this is extremely uncommon). Better to use standard variable substitutions.

Comment: Yes. STD sub must be the choice.

Comment: I tried to remove first symbols: number and "-" with  command

find -type f -name '*.ext' | rename 's/5-//'  

but I get the output "rename: not enough arguments"

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop:

```bsh
for name in *.ext; do 
    newname=${name%%_*}.ext
    newname=${newname#*-}
    echo mv -- "$name" "$newname"
done
```

This loops over all names that end with `.ext` in the current directory (so change to the directory in question first).  For each such name, the `newname` variable is first set to the part of the name before its first `_` character, with `.ext` added to the end.  The value before the first `-` character is then removed to create the final `newname` value.

The two parameter substitutions `${variable%%pattern}` and `${variable#pattern}` used here removes the longest substring matching `pattern` from the end of the `$variable` value, and the shortest matching substring from the start, respectively.

Run with the `echo` command in place to see that it's doing the correct thing, and then remove `echo` in front of `mv` to actually rename files.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `rename`:

```
rename 's/^[^-]+-([^_]+).+(\.[^.]+)$/$1$2/' *.ext
```

would extract the part between the first `-` and the first `_`, and append the extension to it. Try with `rename -n '...'` first, and remove the `-n` when satisfied.

The syntax uses capture groups to break the original filename into

- Everything from the beginning to the first `-`: `^[^-]+-`, i.e. string starting with one or more characters that are *not* `-`, followed by one `-`.
- a "capture group" containing everything after that, up to but excluding the first `_`: `([^_]+)`, i.e. one or more characters that are not `_` - the actual value can later be referenced as `$1` in the replacement text
- everything after that, up to but excluding the *last* `.`: `.+` which actually only means "one or more character of any kind" - the meaning of "up to the last `.`" comes from the definition of the last part
- a "capture group" containing the last `.` and everything after that up to the end-of-string: `(\.[^.]+)$` - this formulation imposes that the capture group content starts with a literal `.` and then contains only characters that are *not* `.`, up to the end of string `$`; only this ensure that the previous group gobbles everything up to but excluding the last `.`. Again, the actual content can later be referenced as `$2` (since it is the second capture group in the regular expression).

The replacement text then only consists of the actual content of the two capture groups: `$1$2`.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to AdminBees solution, maybe easier for you to adapt to other problems, you can use bash builtin functionality like so:

```
for file in *
do
    if [[ "$file" =~ ^[^-]*-([^_]+)_.*\.ext$ ]]
    then
        mv "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.ext"
    fi
done
```

What that does:

`for` *variable* `in` *list of space separated items*

loops through every item in the list, setting *variable* and executing the commands between `do` and `done`.

The * means *every file in current directory*, try `echo *`.
`[[` is bashs builtin version of the old `test` command: [Documentation](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS)

Now to unpack that complicated regular expression:

`^` - *Beginning of input line*
followed by `[^-]` - *any character except* `-`, `*` - *repeated any number of times*, followed by a `-`. Now the part between `()` is what you are interested in. Bash saves matched parts between parentheses to the array `BASH_REMATCH` [(link)](http://molk.ch/tips/gnu/bash/rematch.html). The regexp for that is `[^_]+`, meaning *any character except* `_`, *repeated at least once*, followed by a `_`.

`.` - *any character*, `*` repeated any number of times*, followed by `\.` a literal `.` (see [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html)), followed by `ext` and `$`, the *end of the input (line)*.

Since the input was our filename, this extracts the first part between `-` and `_` and saves that to `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`. If the input file name matched that pattern, we simply use the regular old `mv` to rename `$file` to `our_matched_part.ext`, quotes are not strictly neccessary if your file names do not contain spaces, but are good practice.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: Ah, crap. AdminBee edited their post, I did not see that. Oh, well...

EDIT2: You can further restrict the regexp to only rename specific files, instead of every file `*-something_*.ext`, by adding more literal parts, or for example `[0-9]+` for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls  11-Vnnn_S2_L001_aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd.ext| awk -F "[-_]" '{print "mv " $0" "  $2".ext"}' |sh
```

Tested and worked fine

Comment: Please take the time to consider @Kusalanandas [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617760/rename-specific-files#comment1155465_617760) on why this should preferably not be done with text-processing tools.

Comment: sure will check